# MUI Multiline event.target.value not showing \n

Tags: material-ui, textbox

I currently have a multiline text box and whenever a new line is created via the website, it's not reflected in the backend with a \n.

The goal is to have each new line equate to a \n whenever the event.target.value is called.

`

```
const [welcomeText, setwelcomeText] = React.useState(welcome.welcomeText);
  const handleWelcomeTextChange = (event) => {
    setwelcomeText(event.target.value);

  };
```

`

`

```
 <TextField
          id="outlined-multiline-flexible"
          label="Welcome Text Description"
          multiline
          fullWidth
          maxRows={10}
          value={welcomeText}
          defaultValue={welcome.welcomeText}
          onChange={handleWelcomeTextChange}
        />
```

`

I've tried to implement a fix to detect spacing and convert it to a \n however this didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can actually use the add a style prop to the typography component

```
<Typography style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-line' }}>{'hello \nMUI'}</Typography>
```

I spent almost an hour looking for the solutions to that stupid `\n` too.

Hope it helps.